# Micro-frontend in Angular 16 with Module Federation, HTML not loading in element

Tags: angular, micro-frontend, webpack-module-federation, angular16

I created 2 Angular 16 projects, 1 host and 1 remote. I based my code on the [MF Flight Tutorial](https://github.com/angular-architects/module-federation-plugin)
instead of having 1 Angular project I separated them into 2 projects the shell-ui (host) and the launch-ui (remote).

My problem is when I run both projects the launch-element does not load any data and it doesn't give me any errors. I also added the link to the React Version: ^17.0.1 from the FM tutorial and the data gets displayed.

Here is my route code (app.routes.ts) in the shell-ui project:

```
export const APP_ROUTES: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    component: NotFoundComponent, 
    pathMatch: 'full',
  },
{
 path: 'launch',
  component: WebComponentWrapper,
  data: {
    type: 'module',
    remoteEntry:
      'http://localhost:4202/remoteEntry.js',
    remoteName: 'launch',
    exposedModule: './launch',
    elementName: 'launch-element',
  } as WebComponentWrapperOptions,
},
  {
    path: 'react',
    component: WebComponentWrapper,
    data: {
      type: 'script',
      remoteEntry:
        'https://witty-wave-0a695f710.azurestaticapps.net/remoteEntry.js',
      remoteName: 'react',
      exposedModule: './web-components',
      elementName: 'react-element',
    } as WebComponentWrapperOptions,
  },
```

Here is my code in the launch-ui webpack.config.js file:

```
plugins: [
    new ModuleFederationPlugin({
        library: { type: "module" },

        // For remotes (please adjust)
         name: "launch",
         filename: "remoteEntry.js",
         exposes: {
             './launch': '/src/app/launch/launch.module.ts',
         },        
           
        shared: share({
          "@angular/core": { singleton: true, strictVersion: true, requiredVersion: 'auto' }, 
          "@angular/common": { singleton: true, strictVersion: true, requiredVersion: 'auto' }, 
          "@angular/common/http": { singleton: true, strictVersion: true, requiredVersion: 'auto' }, 
          "@angular/router": { singleton: true, strictVersion: true, requiredVersion: 'auto' },

          ...sharedMappings.getDescriptors()
        })
        
    }),
```

Here is a screenshot of the launch-element with no data:
[image: launch element screenshot]

Here is a screenshot of the react-element with data:
[image: React element screen]

I've also uploaded my code in Github
[Github shell-ui](https://github.com/davcyr/shell-ui)
[Github launch-ui](https://github.com/davcyr/launch-ui)